R Sankey Diagram
I want to create a Sankey diagram looking at different stages. I used the code:
# Load necessary libraries
library(networkD3)
library(dplyr)


# Group by clinical and pathologic stages, count the number of transitions
links <- d_filtered %>%
  count(cl_max_stage, p_max_stage_T1) %>%
  rename(source = cl_max_stage, target = p_max_stage_T1, value = n)

# Print the links to see the result
print(links)


# Step 2: Correct connection data frame for flows between stages
# Create a valid connection data frame, ensuring source and target match
links <- data.frame(
  source=c("Ta","Tis","T1"),  # Define sources
  target=c("T1","T1","T1"),   # Define corresponding targets
  value=c(48, 20, 285)              # Define flow values for each connection
)

# Step 3: Create a node data frame from the unique values of source and target
nodes <- data.frame(
  name=c(as.character(links$source), as.character(links$target)) %>% unique()
)

# Step 4: Reformat the links data to use ID indexes instead of stage names
links$IDsource <- match(links$source, nodes$name) - 1 
links$IDtarget <- match(links$target, nodes$name) - 1

# Step 5: Create the Sankey diagram
p <- sankeyNetwork(
  Links = links, Nodes = nodes,
  Source = "IDsource", Target = "IDtarget",
  Value = "value", NodeID = "name", 
  sinksRight = FALSE  # Controls the direction of the diagram
)

# Display the Sankey diagram
p



The output shwos T1 as a circle, instead of a flow from Stage 1 to Stage 2. How can I fix the Problem?
I have also tried the code from here:
https://r-charts.com/flow/sankey-diagram-ggplot2/
with the same result.

The third link in your data goes from T1 to T1, so the loop represents this self referential link.

I believe the issue is with your data, you are supposed to use different variables or columns for the source and target, Here is updated the data below,
links <- data.frame(
  source=c("Ta","Tis","T1"),  # Define sources
  target=c("Ta1","Tis1","T11"),   # Define corresponding targets
  value=c(48, 20, 285)              # Define flow values for each connection
)

# Step 3: Create a node data frame from the unique values of source and target
nodes <- data.frame(
  name=c(as.character(links$source), as.character(links$target)) %>% unique()
)

# Step 4: Reformat the links data to use ID indexes instead of stage names
links$IDsource <- match(links$source, nodes$name) - 1 
links$IDtarget <- match(links$target, nodes$name) - 1

  source target value IDsource IDtarget
1     Ta    Ta1    48        0        3
2    Tis   Tis1    20        1        4
3     T1    T11   285        2        5

sankeyNetwork(
  Links = links, Nodes = nodes,
  Source = "IDsource", Target = "IDtarget",
  Value = "value", NodeID = "name", 
  sinksRight = FALSE  # Controls the direction of the diagram
)


